# what is the meaning of "da"

Tags: meaning

In Slow German podcast #185 there is this sentence,

> Seine zweite große Expedition brachte ihn nach Russland, da war er aber schon 60 Jahre alt.

I do not understand the English meaning and function of "da" in this sentence. It looks as if it could mean "but", however I cannot find a reference for this meaning of da.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a lonely **da** is a backreference to a previous sentence. It's like a pointing finger to some previously mentioned fact.

> Ich war um Punkt Zwölf am Bahnsteig. Der Zug war **da** aber schon abgefahren.

*I was on the platform at twelve o'clock straight. The train had already departed **then** though.*

> Tja. **Da** kann man nichts machen.

Well. You can't do anything **about it**.

> Nimm doch den nächsten Zug. **Da** muss doch bald einer kommen.

*Just take the next train. **There** has to be one soon.*

That position of **da** as the first item of the main clause just makes it the topic of that clause. It's the same in your example, as these are concatenated main clauses.

You could also use a full stop and/or rearrange *er* and *da* to make the subject the topic instead of *da*.

> Seine zweite große Expedition brachte ihn nach Russland. **Da** war er aber schon 60 Jahre alt.
>
> Seine zweite große Expedition brachte ihn nach Russland. Er war **da** aber schon 60 Jahre alt.

*He was 60 years old **by then** already.*

Comment: You are missing one of the main dictionary meanings of "da". In German, it's often used for time instead of "als" (eng. ' when' ) https://www.dwds.de/wb/da under the II section.

Comment: I did not mean to explain all the possible meanings of *da* but those which apply here. That *als* meaning introduces a *subordinate clause* which isn't the case in the question. *Seine zweite große Expedition brachte ihn nach Russland, als er schon 60 Jahre alt war.* or *Seine zweite große Expedition brachte ihn nach Russland, da er schon 60 Jahre alt war.* You can tell it from word order this meaning does not apply here. I also don't think this if *often used*, as it is easily misunderstood as *weil* – *because*.

Comment: I don't quite agree, I believe that the two meanings coincide here - not unlike the English "when" in a subordinate clause. All the more reason not to leave out the temporal meaning of "da" as per the way the question was asked.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. It has provided a precise, clear and very helpful answer to my question and given me considerable insight into the language. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Ein *but* korrespondiert vielleicht mit dem *aber*. Das *da*, da es in der Vergangenheit spielt, könnte man durch ein *damals* ersetzen. Wir haben aber eine zeitliche (zweite Expedition), räumliche (Russland) und semantische Bestimmung (Expedition).

> Es war 1942, da herrschte Krieg in Europa. (damals)

It's been 1942, when war ruled over Europe.

> Wir leben in der Eifel. Da findet sich Vulkangestein. (dort)

We live in the Eifel. There you find vulcanic stones.

> Wir haben es mit Integerarithmetik zu tun, da wird nicht gerundet, sondern abgeschnitten. (auf diesem Gebiet)

We deal with integer arithmetic, where you don't round, but cut off.

> Seine zweite große Expedition brachte ihn nach Russland, da war er aber schon 60 Jahre alt.

His second, big expedition took him to Russia, where/when he was already 60 years old.

Das ist allerdings nahezu Wort für Wort übersetzt - ein Muttersprachler Englisch würde womöglich eher anders formulieren.